# Full Text Scholarly Resources

Tags: data-request, api, research

Most of scientific paper sources provide some basic metadata about the paper (authors, publish date, DOI, etc) and sometimes the abstract and a link to the PDF of the paper. However, converting PDF to some structured data format like XML is a very tedious method,error prone and not scalable. After some research, I found some sources like CORE (https://core.ac.uk/services#dataset), Elsevier (https://dev.elsevier.com/sc_apis.html) and Springer (https://dev.springernature.com/) which provide the full text of the paper in XML or HTML format which is very usefull for data mining processes.

Are there any other scholarly sources which provide the full text of the papers in a format like XML or HTML ?

Comment: This may be related https://stackoverflow.com/q/10507049/2327328, although your question with full text will be harder since many papers are paywalled.

Comment: Can you please add links to documentation about the sources you found? So that people can use them if needed.

Comment: Also, see especially the CrossRef answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004100/2327328

Comment: I added the links for the soources I mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Three datasets come to my mind.

- The largest one is [The Semantic Scholar Open Research Corpus (S2ORC)](https://github.com/allenai/s2orc), comprising 12.7M+ full text papers from various disciplines.
- Another cross-disciplinary dataset (of 40k full-text papers) is [the Elsevier OA CC-BY Corpus](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.00774).
- Another final that is, however, merely reduced to COVID-related papers, is [CORD-19: The Covid-19 Open Research Dataset](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7251955/).

**EDIT:**

I found a fourth one, called [*unarXive*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11192-020-03382-z). It is based on more than a million *arXiv* pre-prints, it is freely available, and contains rich metadata.